# Is it possible to sanitize leather without damaging it?

Tags: furniture

I am wondering if it is possible to sanitize leather (primarily leather couches and car seats) to avoid potential risk of coronavirus. I know rubbing alcohol is a common option but I recently read that especially applying to to a big area will dry out the leather and potentially strip away leather dye. Are there any other options?

Comment: Has you couch been ignoring the social distancing rules? Is  this a Home Improvement DIY question. Perhaps a little research on "Sanitizing my home in the age of Covid19" https://saddlebackleather.com/how-to-disinfect-leather - https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/prevent-getting-sick/disinfecting-your-home.html

Comment: Car seats are super easy, just park outdoors.  Solar UV light is VERY powerful and will make short work of any SARS-COV2 cells.  They are actually quite fragile and newer science has proven that surface spread (fomites) simply isn't the threat it was initially thought to be.  (on the other hand, aerosolization is much worse than expected! They proved cases where it went 30' in a restaurant because of the ventilation flow. They won't tell Americans that 6' social distancing isn't even enough... because that narrative is politically impossible to sell.)

Comment: Interesting. I was under the impression that glass blocks solar uv though? That's why people leave masks outside for a day to sanitize instead of on the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Soap and water are even more effective than alcohol on covid-19, per a number of sources. [Here's one.](https://www.uchealth.org/today/why-soap-and-water-work-better-than-hand-sanitizer-to-remove-the-coronavirus/)

Saddle soap is literally soap made for use on leather.

[image: Picture from Tractor supply, but appears to be stock picture from the maker]

Enjoy.

Comment: Saddle soap is good for leather and will even clean mold and mildew. (We always have at least one saddle that needs a good cleaning) but use it on car seats and our living room furniture.